# Removing a loaded persistentStore in persistentContainer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspersistentstore

I have loaded a specific URL file in persistentContainer using the following:

```
// MARK: Core Data Stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
  os_log("In persistent Container", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

  // set URL to game file location
  let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
  let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
  let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent(Singleton.sharedInstance.mainGameFileName!)

  let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "RefGameData")
  container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)]
  container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  })

  return container
}()
```

I want to remove that particular URL file and replace it with a different file when I need to load a different game's data.  I have not be able to locate in the Apple documentation for persistentContainer any equivalent to `container.unloadPersistentStores(....)`

I am a noobie in Swift programming and any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the persistent store coordinator for that. `NSPersistentContainer` has a property called `persistentStoreController`, and **that** has a method called `remove`, which does what you're looking for.

Keep in mind that if you remove a persistent store, you must be absolutely sure that you don't have any managed objects in memory that were loaded from that store. They will not be useful any more and might make the app crash if you try to use them.

Comment: I think it's `persistentStoreCoordinator`.: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640567-persistentstorecoordinator

Comment: @Tom Harrington what will happen on NSPersistentContainer deinit? Will stores be removed?

Comment: @Oranutachi They won’t be available in the app any more, so they’re removed from memory. The files don’t get deleted, so you could reload them later.